# kafka consumer receiving overhead?

Tags: apache-kafka, wireshark

I have a kafka consumer that does a poll every 10 seconds. I am using wireshark to monitor my network's acitvity.

I noticed that even when I am not doing any fetch requests, there is still traffic between the broker and my consumer. And I also noticed that it is the same packets (almost the same, only a slight change to the payload) that are sent and received periodically.

Is this some kind of keep alive packets? how to reduce them?

Here is a screenshot of those packets:
[image]

PS: I am using cppkafka as lib and kafka broker 0.8.2.2

EDIT: The client's code

```
bool running = true;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    string brokers;
    string topic_name;
    string group_id;

    po::options_description options("Options");
    options.add_options()
        ("help,h",     "produce this help message")
        ("brokers,b",  po::value<string>(&brokers)->required(), 
                       "the kafka broker list")
        ("topic,t",    po::value<string>(&topic_name)->required(),
                       "the topic in which to write to")
        ("group-id,g", po::value<string>(&group_id)->required(),
                       "the consumer group id")
        ;

    po::variables_map vm;

    try {
        po::store(po::command_line_parser(argc, argv).options(options).run(), vm);
        po::notify(vm);
    }
    catch (exception& ex) {
        cout << "Error parsing options: " << ex.what() << endl;
        cout << endl;
        cout << options << endl;
        return 1;
    }

    // Stop processing on SIGINT
    signal(SIGINT, [](int) { running = false; });

    // Construct the configuration
    Configuration config = {
        { "metadata.broker.list", brokers },
        { "api.version.request", false },
        { "broker.version.fallback", "0.8.2.2" },   
        { "group.id", group_id },
        // Disable auto commit
        { "enable.auto.commit", false }
    };

    // Create the consumer
    Consumer consumer(config);

    // Subscribe to the topic
    TopicPartitionList topicList;
    cppkafka::TopicPartition topPar(topic_name,0);
    topPar.set_offset(0);
    topicList.push_back(topPar);
    cout << "Consuming messages from topic " << topic_name << endl;

    consumer.assign(topicList);

    // Now read lines and write them into kafka
    while (running) {
        // Try to consume a message
        Message msg = consumer.poll();
        if (msg) {
            // If we managed to get a message
            if (msg.get_error()) {
                // Ignore EOF notifications from rdkafka
                if (!msg.is_eof()) {
                    cout << "[+] Received error notification: " << msg.get_error() << endl;
                } else {
                    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(10000));
                }
            } else {
                // Print the key (if any)
                if (msg.get_key()) {
                    cout << msg.get_key() << " -> ";
                }
                // Print the payload
                cout << msg.get_payload() << endl;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you enable the Kafka plugin, Wireshark will show you the type of request each packet is. To enable it, go to Preferences, select Kafka in the list of protocols, and set the port to 9092

Comment: Thanks for othe tip, they are fetch requests and fetch responses. I don't know why there are any fetch requests when I am doing nothing!

Comment: Can you share your client code ?

Comment: @MickaelMaison I added the client code to the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cppkafka is built on top of librdkafka. Librdkafka attempts to prefetch messages for all assigned partitions, so messages are immediately available when you call poll().

By default, librdkafka pretty aggressive (aiming for best performance), hence the few FetchRequests per second you're seeing.

For more details, see librdkafka's FAQ:

- https://github.com/edenhill/librdkafka/wiki/FAQ#how-are-partitions-fetched
- https://github.com/edenhill/librdkafka/wiki/FAQ#my-otherwise-idle-consumer-is-taking-1-2-cpu

Comment: If the message is EOF I sleep for 10 seconds (`std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(10000))`) 
I also commented all the code that is inside the loop and noticed that I still get all the FetchRequests. To stop that behavior I had to call `unassign()`. So I am sure that the problem comes from the `assign()`but I don't know why...

Comment: My bad, I had not noticed cppkafka was a librdkafka wrapper. I updated my answer

Comment: Had this 'issue' as well. Increasing fetch.max.wait.ms decreased the idle network traffic.

Answer (score 0):

You probably see [heartbeat messages](http://kafka.apache.org/protocol.html#The_Messages_Heartbeat) to keep the consumer group alive, you can find more info about them here: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/A+Guide+To+The+Kafka+Protocol#AGuideToTheKafkaProtocol-GroupMembershipAPI

It's possible to adjust the heartbeat interval by modifying **heartbeat.interval.ms**, check the [librdkafka configuration](https://github.com/edenhill/librdkafka/blob/master/CONFIGURATION.md).

Comment: Unfortunately it was not that. I noticed that these packets are sent when I call the `assign(TopicPartitions)` on a consumer and they are stopped when I call `unassign()`. It can be a work around to call the assign and unassign when I want to read but I don't think that it is the best way to do it ...